# Is there any python function to check for nan values in list comprehension without changing it

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, nan

I am writing code to take values from everyone column of data frame and do some processing on it. I got exception whenever there is a NaN value. I do not want to drop columns with Nan. 
Previously I solved the problem by simply catching exception but now I am unable to do same as I am using list comprehensions here.
Can someone suggest a proper way of doing this ?
Previously I solved it like this:

```
for index, row in df_work.iterrows():
        descrip = row['description']
        try:
            r = Rake()
            r.extract_keywords_from_text(descrip)
            key_words_dict_scores = r.get_word_degrees()
            row['Key_words'] = list(key_words_dict_scores.keys())
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            row['Key_words'] = ''
```

I want to do same here:

```
df_work['specialties'] = [','.join(x) for x in df_work['specialties'].map(lambda x: x.lower().replace(' ','').split(',')).values]
    df_work['industry'] = [','.join(x) for x in df_work['industry'].map(lambda x: x.lower().replace(' ','').split(',')).values]
    df_work['type'] = [','.join(x) for x in df_work['type'].map(lambda x: x.lower().replace(' ','').split(',')).values]
```

I get this error in above code:

```
'float' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Specialties column contains data like this:

```
df_work.loc['TOTAL', 'specialties']
```

OUTPUT >> `'Oil & Gas - Exploration & Production,Upstream,Refining,Trading,Shipping,Marketing,Energy,Crude Oil,Petroleum,Petrochemicals,Liquified Natural Gas,Renewable Energy,Drilling Engineering,Completion & Intervention Engineering,Geology,Geoscientists,IT'`

```
type(df_work.loc['TOTAL', 'specialties'])
```

OUTPUT>> `str`

Expected output after running my above code should be:
OUTPUT>> `'oil&gas-exploration&production,upstream,refining,trading,shipping,marketing,energy,crudeoil,petroleum,petrochemicals,liquifiednaturalgas,renewableenergy,drillingengineering,completion&interventionengineering,geology,geoscientists,it'`

```
type(df_work.loc['TOTAL', 'specialties'])
```

OUTPUT>> `str`

Comment: Is possible add some sample data, 3 rows e.g. for `specialties` column ?

Comment: added. kindly check again

Comment: Can you check my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is possible use pandas functions working with `NaN`s nice:

```
df_work['specialties'] = df_work['specialties'].str.lower().str.replace(' ','')
```

If need working with `NaN`s test it by `isinstance()` and `if-else` statement:

```
df_work['specialties'] = (df_work['specialties']
        .map(lambda x: x.lower().replace(' ','') if isinstance(x, str) else x))
```

And list comprehension solution:

```
df_work['specialties'] = [x.lower().replace(' ','') 
                          if isinstance(x, str) 
                          else x 
                          for x in df_work['specialties']]
```

**Sample**:

```
df_work = pd.DataFrame({'specialties':['First spec, Sec spec','A Vb,ds RT', np.nan]})
print (df_work)
            specialties
0  First spec, Sec spec
1            A Vb,ds RT
2                   NaN

df_work['specialties'] = [x.lower().replace(' ','') 
                          if isinstance(x, str) 
                          else x 
                          for x in df_work['specialties']]
print (df_work)
         specialties
0  firstspec,secspec
1           avb,dsrt
2                NaN
```

Comment: yes its working now. I got an error but it was something else. Thanks:)